# ¿Cómo reorganizar un data frame?

Tags: r

Me gustaría reorganizar un dataframe de tal manera que teniendo este dataframe:

```
 df:

    Spp     Habitat    Site
 Solanum    Edge       L1V
 Solanum    Edge       L1V
 Solanum    Edge       L2V
 Solanum    Edge       L3V
 Solanum    Edge       L1F
 Solanum    Crop       M1V
 Solanum    Crop       M1V
 Solanum    Crop       M4V
 Taraxacum  Oakwood    Q1F
```

se reorganice así:

```
Spp       Habitat      Site
Solanum    Edge         L1V/L2V/L3V/L1F
Solanum    Crop         M1V/M4V
Taraxacum  Oakwood      Q1F
```

¿Qué función podría usar?

Muchas gracias de antemano,
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Adrian Si tenemos el data.frame que señalas

```
Spp <- c("Solanum","Solanum","Solanum","Solanum","Solanum","Solanum","Solanum","Solanum","Taraxacum")
Habitat <- c("Edge", "Edge","Edge","Edge","Edge","Crop","Crop","Crop","Oakwood")
Site <- c("L1V","L1V","L2V","L3V","L1F","M1V","M1V","M4V","Q1F")
df<-data.frame(Spp=Spp, Habitat=Habitat, Site=Site)
```

Se observa que, si algunas filas fueran encadenas, se repiten.

Por ejemplo fila 1 y fila 2, el cada valor de la columna `Site` debería corresponder a un único valor de `Spp` y `Habitat`. Para eso aplicamos lo siguiente

```
df <- unique(df)
#         Spp Habitat Site
# 1   Solanum    Edge  L1V
# 3   Solanum    Edge  L2V
# 4   Solanum    Edge  L3V
# 5   Solanum    Edge  L1F
# 6   Solanum    Crop  M1V
# 8   Solanum    Crop  M4V
# 9 Taraxacum Oakwood  Q1F
```

Con la data pre-estructurada, se puede aplicar encadenamiento (o tuberías) con la biblioteca `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    # Se quiere que la colummna Habitat muestre a ese nivel a la 
    # columna Site como factor
    group_by(Habitat) %>%  

    # Colapsamos cada valor de Site ya agrupado por la columna Habitat
    # en la nueva columna SiteFactor
    mutate(SiteFactor = paste0(Site, collapse = "/")) %>% 

    select(-Site)   # eliminamos la columna Site de df

    %>% unique      # como arriba, eliminamos los duplicados de
                    # la columna SiteFactor
```

> **El resultado final**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Habitat [3]
  Spp       Habitat SiteFactor     
  <fct>     <fct>   <chr>          
1 Solanum   Edge    L1V/L2V/L3V/L1F
2 Solanum   Crop    M1V/M4V        
3 Taraxacum Oakwood Q1F
```

> **NOTA:** También pudo hacerse directamente, sólo fue para que se apreciara lo expuesto inicialmente.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    unique %>%
    group_by(Habitat) %>% 
    mutate(SiteFactor = paste0(Site, collapse = "/")) %>% 
    select(-Site) %>%
    unique
```

Comment: Gracias Hubert por tu pronta respuesta. He ejecutado el script y como bien has mostrado con ese dataframe funciona. En cambio, con mi dataframe (ya que lo que escribí era una recreación pequeña) no funciona. He cambiado el factor por el que colapso la tabla y en vez de ser por Habitat lo colapso por spp (group_by(spp)) y así si funciona. Aun así aparece la spp Solanum en el hábitat edge con L1V/L2V/L3V/L1F/M1V/M4V y otra vez aparece la misma spp pero en el hábitat Crop y con la misma secuencia de sitios L1V/L2V/L3V/L1F/M1V/M4V ¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Comment: @AdriánP.L. Entiendo tu punto, el dataframe en este caso es una especie de organigrama: `Solanum` tiene como subordinados a `Edge` y `Crop` y a su vez estos tienen como subordinados a `L1V/L2V/L3V/L1F` y `M1V/M4V` respectivamente, por tanto estos 6 últimos (agrupados en dos) son subordinados también de `Solanum`, en tal sentido cuando se aplica `group_by(Spp)` se omite a los de mando medio (`Habitat`) y los 6 últimos pasan a ser subordinados directos de `Solanum` y por eso se obtiene `L1V/L2V/L3V/L1F/M1V/M4V` el resultado que expones.

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor, creo que si pudieras incluir en la parte final de tu pregunta **¿Cómo reorganizar un df?** la casuística del `df` que está ocasionando lo que señalas e incluir lo que esperas conseguir, será más sencillo para la comunidad testear posibles soluciones. Para terminar no olvides en el código posteado asignar el resultado a una nueva variable `df2 <- df %>% unique %>% ...` para trabajar con la data que quieres obtener, por ejemplo `df2 %>% unique %>% group_by(SiteFactor) %>% mutate(HabitatFactor = paste0(Habitat, collapse = "/")) %>% select(-Habitat) %>% unique`

Answer (score 2):

La versión con R base, en este caso, no es para nada compleja

```
aggregate(Site ~ Spp + Habitat, unique(df), paste, collapse="/")
```

- Agrupamos por `Spp` y `Habitat` sobre los valores únicos de `df`
- Aplicamos `paste()` a los valores de `Site` de cada grupo

Comment: ambas soluciones funcionan para lo que necesitaba, gracias a los dos